# Possible to sum some cells after a certain date if a matching date is entered in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a function to sort out some loan interest payments. Essentially I have made a sheet that has a value in each month heading for how much interest is owed that month. But I need to now also look at if the loan is repaid early. Essentially it will be that if the 'Actual loan repayment date' is empty, then values are as normal, but if the month of the repayment date matches the month in the header, then the value for that cell equals all the remaining months summed, and thereafter the remaining months become zero. Or that the final payment = the total interest owed - any previous payments.

so far I cant figure this out as it seems what I want to do will self reference and cant work, but also open to adding extra sheets. any advice is greatly appreciated.

also worth noting that the loans pay a fixed interest regardless of whether they pay back on time or early.

below I have attached a sample of what I am working with, essentially any cells in the box highlighted in red need to be summed and added to the cells before, but I need it to be automatic for thousands of entries across different date ranges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

[Sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFO4u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think this will do what you want

I have the funding on in column D, expect date in E, actual date in F
This formula is in G2

```vb
=IF(G$1<$D2,0,IF(AND(G$1<=$E2,OR(G$1<$F2,ISBLANK($F2))),the_interest_formula,IF(G$1<=DATE(YEAR($F2),MONTH($F2)+1,1),total_interest_formula-SUMIFS($G2:$Z2,$G1:$Z1,"<"&G$1),0)))
```

Using the sumifs and giving the criteria of < the month for that cell gets around the self-reference. SUMIFS($G2:$Z2,$G1:$Z1,"<"&G$1)